# PDF manipulator for Python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I need to extract the data out of a PDF file in python which I can manipulate. If there's a bullet  point, I need to understand that a particular text was a bullet point of such and such font and size, the page has such and such margins and tables etc.
I would prefer to get the data out of a PDF line by line with all the information. Currently I can get the text out but not the information.

Comment: See https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167